# Complex SQL query optimization

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to optimize an SQL query.  Can you help me?

Basically each user has friends through a friendship table and each user has many feed_events trough a user_feed_events table.
I'm trying to list the feed_events of the friends of a given user.  Shouldn't be impossible, right? :)

As you can see the performance of the query depends on how many friends a user has.  Right now a user with 150 friends takes almost 7 seconds to execute.

**UPDATE:** here is how my friendship table is built:

```
create_table "friendships", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "user_id",     :null => false
t.integer  "friend_id",   :null => false
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "accepted_at"
end

add_index "friendships", ["friend_id"], :name => "index_friendships_on_friend_id"
add_index "friendships", ["user_id"], :name => "index_friendships_on_user_id"
```

First I ask rails to give me the list of the ids of the userids of the friends of the user, then I use this string on the real query.

```
friends_id = current_user.friends.collect {|f| f.id}.join(",")

sql = "
SELECT 
DISTINCT feed_events.id, 
feed_events.event_type, 
feed_events.type_id, 
feed_events.data, 
feed_events.created_at, 
feed_events.updated_at, 
user_feed_events.user_id  
FROM feed_events 
LEFT JOIN user_feed_events 
ON feed_events.id = user_feed_events.feed_event_id 
WHERE user_feed_events.user_id IN (#{friends_id}) 
ORDER BY feed_events.created_at DESC"
```

Then I acutally execute the query (paginating it and limiting to 30 results):

```
@events = FeedEvent.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

**UPDATE #2:** HERE IS THE EXPLAIN ANALYZE OUTPUT:

```
    SQL> EXPLAIN ANALYZE (SELECT  DISTINCT feed_events.id,  feed_events.event_type,  feed_events.type_id,  feed_events.data,  feed_events.created_at,  feed_events.updated_at,  user_feed_events.user_id   FROM user_feed_events  INNER JOIN feed_events  ON feed_events.id = user_feed_events.feed_event_id  WHERE user_feed_events.user_id IN (1,7,9,8,14,15,20,35,40,39,41,42,57,84,98,109,121,74,129,64,137,77,172,182,206,201,284,31,94,232,311,168,30,114,50,174,419,403,438,464,423,513,351,349,385,622,751,359,809,838,844,962,831,786,896,1001,992,998,990,256,67,623,957,1226,1060,1009,1490,132,1467,1672,619,1459,1466,993,1599,1365,607,1381,1714,1154,2032,2230,2240,2354,598,2345,1804,634,1900,2652,1975,2164,1759,3288,1004,3487,3507,3542,3566,514,3787,3137,3803,3090,4012,855,17,2026,1463,335,1000,935,5,12,10,13,19,18,16,22,34,27,29,59,126,90,46,23,63,291,134,229,107,439,521)  ORDER BY feed_events.created_at DESC)
    +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
    +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Unique  (cost=6090.87..6162.93 rows=18014 width=389) (actual time=1641.210..1733.010 rows=29691 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
    |   ->  Sort  (cost=6090.87..6099.88 rows=18014 width=389) (actual time=1641.206..1670.882 rows=29694 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
    |         Sort Key: feed_events.created_at, feed_events.id, feed_events.event_type, feed_events.type_id, feed_events.data, feed_events.updated_at, user_feed_events.user_id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
    |         Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 17755kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
    |         ->  Hash Join  (cost=3931.63..5836.21 rows=18014 width=389) (actual time=258.541..361.345 rows=29694 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
    |               Hash Cond: (user_feed_events.feed_event_id = feed_events.id)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
    |               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on user_feed_events  (cost=926.64..2745.66 rows=18014 width=8) (actual time=6.930..42.367 rows=29694 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
    |                     Recheck Cond: (user_id = ANY ('{1,7,9,8,14,15,20,35,40,39,41,42,57,84,98,109,121,74,129,64,137,77,172,182,206,201,284,31,94,232,311,168,30,114,50,174,419,403,438,464,423,513,351,349,385,622,751,359,809,838,844,962,831,786,896,1001,992,998,990,256,67,623,957,1226,1060,1009,1490,132,1467,1672,619,1459,1466,993,1599,1365,607,1381,1714,1154,2032,2230,2240,2354,598,2345,1804,634,1900,2652,1975,2164,1759,3288,1004,3487,3507,3542,3566,514,3787,3137,3803,3090,4012,855,17,2026,1463,335,1000,935,5,12,10,13,19,18,16,22,34,27,29,59,126,90,46,23,63,291,134,229,107,439,521}'::integer[]))     |
    |                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_user_feed_events_on_user_id  (cost=0.00..925.74 rows=18014 width=0) (actual time=6.836..6.836 rows=29694 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
    |                           Index Cond: (user_id = ANY ('{1,7,9,8,14,15,20,35,40,39,41,42,57,84,98,109,121,74,129,64,137,77,172,182,206,201,284,31,94,232,311,168,30,114,50,174,419,403,438,464,423,513,351,349,385,622,751,359,809,838,844,962,831,786,896,1001,992,998,990,256,67,623,957,1226,1060,1009,1490,132,1467,1672,619,1459,1466,993,1599,1365,607,1381,1714,1154,2032,2230,2240,2354,598,2345,1804,634,1900,2652,1975,2164,1759,3288,1004,3487,3507,3542,3566,514,3787,3137,3803,3090,4012,855,17,2026,1463,335,1000,935,5,12,10,13,19,18,16,22,34,27,29,59,126,90,46,23,63,291,134,229,107,439,521}'::integer[])) |
    |               ->  Hash  (cost=2848.84..2848.84 rows=44614 width=385) (actual time=251.490..251.490 rows=44663 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
    |                     ->  Seq Scan on feed_events  (cost=0.00..2848.84 rows=44614 width=385) (actual time=0.035..77.044 rows=44663 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
    | Total runtime: 1780.200 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
    +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    SQL>
```

**UPDATE #3** : The problem is that for my rails application I'm using the has_many_friends plugin (https://github.com/swemoney/has_many_friends), that is taking care of my friendships.  It works like this.  I'm user_id #6 and I'm asking friendship to user_id # 10.  When user # 10 accepts my friendship a new row is added to the table with user_id = 6 and friend_id = 10.  If user #10 ask me for friendship the row is: user_id = 10 and friend_id = 6.

This means that in order to find friends_by_me I need to search on "user_id = 6", in order to find friends_for_me I need to "friend_id = 6".  In order to find all of my friends I need to search both columns.   This makes very complicated creating joins!
How would you handle this?

The only alternative I can think of is:

```
"(SELECT 
DISTINCT feed_events.id, 
feed_events.event_type, 
feed_events.type_id, 
feed_events.data, 
feed_events.created_at, 
feed_events.updated_at, 
user_feed_events.user_id 
FROM feed_events 
INNER JOIN user_feed_events 
ON feed_events.id = user_feed_events.feed_event_id 
INNER JOIN friendships 
ON user_feed_events.user_id = friendships.user_id 
WHERE friendships.user_id = 6 
AND friendships.accepted_at IS NOT NULL)

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT 
DISTINCT additional_feed_events.id, 
additional_feed_events.event_type, 
additional_feed_events.type_id, 
additional_feed_events.data, 
additional_feed_events.created_at, 
additional_feed_events.updated_at, 
user_feed_events.user_id 
FROM feed_events AS additional_feed_events 
INNER JOIN user_feed_events 
ON additional_feed_events.id = user_feed_events.feed_event_id 
INNER JOIN friendships 
ON user_feed_events.user_id = friendships.friend_id 
WHERE friendships.friend_id = 6 
AND friendships.accepted_at IS NOT NULL) 

ORDER BY feed_events.created_at DESC"
```

But at the moment is not working and I'm also not sure is the right way to do it!

Thanks,
Augusto

Comment: Please format your SQL statements so they can be read without scrolling.

Comment: Ok, I formatted it.  Should be better now :)

Comment: Can you show the table definitions? Do you have any indices?

Comment: Could you show how friendship table looks like? How friends are matched - friend_id and?

Comment: I updated my question with the details of the friendship table definition.

Comment: What does Explain Analyze have to say?

Comment: @Denis: I added the explain analyze output of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use the IN list? Why don't you start from the selected user? Also, I think your left outer join is not needed:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT feed_events.id, 
feed_events.event_type, 
feed_events.type_id, 
feed_events.data, 
feed_events.created_at, 
feed_events.updated_at, 
user_feed_events.user_id  
FROM 
(
  select friend_id from friendship where user_id = YOURUSER
  UNION
  select user_id as friend_id from friendship where friend_id = YOURUSER
) friendship
inner join user_feed_events 
on friendship.friend_id = user_feed_events.user_id
inner join feed_events
on user_feed_events.feed_event_id = feed_events.id
ORDER BY feed_events.created_at DESC
```

If you want to stay with your original statement and just optimize it, then use this:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT feed_events.id, 
feed_events.event_type, 
feed_events.type_id, 
feed_events.data, 
feed_events.created_at, 
feed_events.updated_at, 
user_feed_events.user_id  
FROM user_feed_events 
INNER JOIN feed_events 
ON feed_events.id = user_feed_events.feed_event_id 
WHERE user_feed_events.user_id IN (#{friends_id}) 
ORDER BY feed_events.created_at DESC
```

This removes the unnecessary LEFT JOIN.

Furthermore, please make sure that you created indexes on the columns you use for the foreign keys.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, as I explain on the updated question, the problem is how the friendship table is built.  In order to find all of my friends I need to look for both user_id and friend_id columns!  How can I handle this inside a join?

Comment: @Augusto: You can use the second statement as a direct replacement for your statement. I will update the first statement to reflect your requirement about the friendship table.

Comment: @Daniel, thank you very much.  I'm using now your edited first proposal and it seems to be more elegant.  Still, though, the query takes 2 seconds to be processed :(  Now I check to be sure that I have all the foreign keys properly indexed.

Comment: @Augusto: Please also try the second query.

Comment: I tried that too, it works but seems to take the same time to process as the first one :(

Comment: @Augusto: Well, 2 seconds is better than 7 seconds, isn't it? :)

Comment: Well yes :)  The problem is that after this query, I process the entries with rails and, for each feed_event of this query Rails calls several queries in order to get the user data of each entry.  The overall time of the process is still around 7 seconds, it appears that now I should find a way to pre-fetch all the data using a single query.  Don't know how to do it though in Rails, after an SQL call (without the SQL call I could avoid this using ActiveRecord and :include =>).

Comment: @Augusto: Yes, you should fetch all your data with one select.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the query isn't your problem here, your database must be set up so that this doesn't take any longer than a few microseconds.  First though, the query.  It should look like this:

```
 SELECT feed_events.id, 
        feed_events.event_type, 
        feed_events.type_id, 
        feed_events.data, 
        feed_events.created_at, 
        feed_events.updated_at, 
        user_feed_events.user_id  

   FROM feed_events
            INNER JOIN
        user_feed_events ON feed_events.id = user_feed_events.feed_event_id
            INNER JOIN
        user_friends     ON user_friends.friend_id = user_feed_events.user_id

  WHERE user_friends.user_id = ** The Id of the User in Question **
  ORDER BY feed_events.created_at DESC
```

Next, you need to make sure your Id columns are primary keys and there are unique indexes on things like (friend_id, user_id) in the user_friends table.  Btw, I just made up those names, I tried to guess what you were calling the table you store friendships in.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct fe.id, fe.event_type,
       fe.type_id, fe.data, fe.created_at,
       fe.updated_at, ufe.user_id
from friendships as f
    inner join user_feed_events as ufe on f.friend_id = ufe.user_id
    inner join feed_events as fe on ufe.user_id = fe.id
where f.user_id = 6 and f.accepted_at is not null
order by fe.created_at desc
```

Not sure whether distinct is really needed here. Query returns feed events for friends of specified user.. it should I hope ;)

Edit.
It occur that solution is pretty the same as Daniel Hilgarth proposed.

Answer (score 0):

User a sub-`SELECT` in the `WHERE` clause to build a list of feed events for an `IN()` call. Something (untested) like this:

```
SELECT fe.id, 
    fe.event_type, 
    fe.type_id, 
    fe.data, 
    fe.created_at, 
    fe.updated_at,
    ufe.user_id  
FROM feed_events AS fe, user_feed_events AS ufe
WHERE TRUE = TRUE
    AND fe.id = ufe.feed_event_id
    AND ufe.user_id = :user_id
    AND fe.id IN((
        SELECT ufe.feed_event_id
        FROM user_feed_events AS ufe, user_friends AS uf
        WHERE uf.friend_id = :user_id
    ))
ORDER BY feed_events.created_at DESC;
```

I'd be curious to see what the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` looks like from this.